# Symfony 3.2 "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service ^my authentication handler^

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

On my personal Symfony 3.2 project (https://github.com/pc-magas/photoalbum) because I wanted to get a Json instead of redirecting based on http://www.webtipblog.com/adding-an-ajax-login-form-to-a-symfony-project/ I made the following authentication Manager:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $session;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @author  Joe Sexton <joe@webtipblog.com>
     * @param   RouterInterface $router
     * @param   Session $session
     */
    public function __construct( RouterInterface $router, Session $session )
    {
        $this->router  = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * onAuthenticationSuccess
     *
     * @author  Joe Sexton <joe@webtipblog.com>
     * @param   Request $request
     * @param   TokenInterface $token
     * @return  Response
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token )
    {
        // if AJAX login
        if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {

            $array = array( 'status' => true ); // data to return via JSON
            $response = new Response( json_encode( $array ) );
            $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

            return $response;

            // if form login
        } else {

            if ( $this->session->get('_security.main.target_path' ) ) {

                $url = $this->session->get( '_security.main.target_path' );

            } else {

                $url = $this->router->generate( 'home_page' );

            } // end if

            return new RedirectResponse( $url );

        }
    }

    /**
     * onAuthenticationFailure
     *
     * @author  Joe Sexton <joe@webtipblog.com>
     * @param   Request $request
     * @param   AuthenticationException $exception
     * @return  Response
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure( Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception )
    {
        // if AJAX login
        if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {

            $array = array( 'status' => false, 'message' => $exception->getMessage() ); // data to return via JSON
            $response = new Response( json_encode( $array ) );
            $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

            return $response;

            // if form login
        } else {

            // set authentication exception to session
            $request->getSession()->set(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);

            return new RedirectResponse( $this->router->generate( 'login_route' ) );
        }
    }
}
```

And I configured my `services.yml` like this:

```
parameters:

services:
  authentication_handler:
    class: AppBundle\Security\AuthenticationHandler
    public: false
    arguments: ["@router","@session"]
```

And I configured `security.yml` like that:

```
security:
   encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

   role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

   providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

   firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                check_path:      security_check_route
                success_handler: authentication_handler
                failure_handler: authentication_handler

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

   access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But I get the following Error:

> The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "authentication_handler".

Do you have any sort of idea how the prob will be solved? I have set the `authentication_handler` my service into `services.yml` file but I get the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you may messed up on how the service have been defined in `services.yml`. Please check the spaces and the yml syntax.

Comment: i declared the handler as a service, and referencing this service in security.yml, but still got the same error

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to add the service

in services.xml

```
 <service id="app.security.authentication_handler" class="AppBundle\Security\AuthenticationHandler">
   <argument type="service" id="router" />
   <argument type="service" id="session" />
   <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
 </service>
```

or in services.yml

```
app.security.authentication_handler:
  class: AppBundle\Security\AuthenticationHandler
  arguments: ["@router", "@session", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```